# jquery class and this selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am trying to find the correct jquery way to select only a certain class within the currently active div:

```
$('.imageScroll').mouseover(function() {
    $('.descBox').filter(this).show(500);
});
```

markup:

```
<li>
<div class="descBox"></div>
</li>
<li>
<div class="descBox"></div>
</li>
```

Comment: .. but which is the currently active div ?

Comment: the one clicked on - ammendment coming

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I understand, you should try `$('.descBox', this)`.

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to show the divs with `.descBox` that are inside the `this` element (which ever that is) then use

```
$('.descBox', this).show(500);
```

Comment: Thanks to all, I really should know my basic jquery syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You mean this:

```
alert($('.descBox').attr('class'));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(this).filter(".descBox").show(500);
```

Usually you use [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to do slightly more complicated things. For example if you changed the background of all the divs inside "this" parent, and then you want to add a border to only the "descBox" class within all the divs with descBox classes inside "this".

Something like this (essentially lifted from the manual):

```
 $("div", this).css("background", "#c8ebcc")
               .filter(".descBox")
               .css("border-color", "red");
```

Maybe in this context:

```
<div>
    <div></div>
    <div class="descBox"></div>
    <div class="descBox"></div>
    <div class="descBox"></div>
    <div class="descBox"></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
<script>
$("div").click(function() 
{    
    $("div", this).css("background", "#c8ebcc")
                  .filter(".middle")
                  .css("border-color", "red");
});
</script>
```